# Slick Slider and IE11

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer, carousel, slick.js

The [slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) has a container for the slides which allow some of the slides/images not to be displayed if they are out of bounds. When using IE 11 the images are still displaying after the carousel has animated/scrolled.

[image]

Attempts with no success:

- Added a z-index and position relative to the master container and child video elements.
- IE is not in compatibility mode
- Issue happens in versions of IE 11 and less
- Similar issue with no resolve: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1911

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/codedcontainer/q7heb3yk/3/)

```
Code can be found in JSFiddle.
```